# tsc incremental build clean output file on source file deletion

Tags: typescript, tsc, incremental-build

I'm experimenting with incremental build to speed up generating `.js` from `.ts` in a large project for local and CI processes. But, I'm facing an issue where deleting a source file doesn't delete the corresponding `.js` file during incremental build. This is causing problems for me because If I have to clean the folder before every build, there would be no point in using the incremental build feature.

Example:

```
.
├── bar.ts
├── foo.ts
├── index.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

After build `npx tsc --build --incremental ./`

```
.
├── bar.js
├── bar.ts
├── foo.js
├── foo.ts
├── index.js
├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
```

Now delete `bar.ts` and run `npx tsc --build --incremental ./`

```
.
├── bar.js
├── foo.js
├── foo.ts
├── index.js
├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
```

`bar.js` won't be deleted.

Is there anything missing in the CLI argument? There is no information about it in the documentation.